# How to check if collection exists in MongoDB using C# driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Is there any way in C# to check if a collection with a specific name already exists in my MongoDB database?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

`database.GetCollection("blah").Exists()`

Comment: @frontsidebus, see my answer bellow

Comment: compile error: Does not contain definition for "Exists" ?

Comment: or in line line as  return db.ListCollectionsAsync(new ListCollectionsOptions { Filter = new BsonDocument("name", fCollectionName) }).Result.Any(); without the asyncs

Comment: This is the wrong answer it should be changed. I don't know if it ever existed before but `.Exists()` does not exist as of `MongoDB.Driver v2.11.0`

Comment: Downvoted, Exists does not exist in latest driver

Answer (score 71):

@im1dermike answer is no longer working for c# driver version 2.0+

Here is an alternative:

```
    public async Task<bool> CollectionExistsAsync(string collectionName)
    {
        var filter = new BsonDocument("name", collectionName);
        //filter by collection name
        var collections = await GetDatabase().ListCollectionsAsync(new ListCollectionsOptions { Filter = filter });
        //check for existence
        return await collections.AnyAsync();
    }
```

Comment: One don't need to `return (await collections.ToListAsync()).Any();`, just `return await collections.AnyAsync();` is fine

Comment: @DineiRockenbach, thanks for your feedback - I've updated my answer

Comment: Use `GetDatabase().ListCollectionNamesAsync(...)` instead of `GetDatabase().ListCollectionsAsync(...)`. Because returning just the name and type (view or collection) does not take collection-level locks whereas returning full collection information locks each collection in the database. Details: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/listCollections/

Answer (score 24):

@Ofir answer is correct. Here's a synchronous alternative built around the `ListCollectionNames` API:

```
public bool CollectionExists(IMongoDatabase database, string collectionName)
{
    var filter = new BsonDocument("name", collectionName);
    var options = new ListCollectionNamesOptions { Filter = filter };

    return database.ListCollectionNames(options).Any();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Above answers are correct but here is another approach with the latest driver (MongoDB.Driver 2.11.6);

```
public async Task<bool> IsCollectionExistsAsync(string collectionName)
{
    MongoClient dbClient = new(_connectionString);

    IMongoDatabase database = dbClient.GetDatabase(_databaseName);

    IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> mongoCollection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collectionName);
            
    if (mongoCollection != null)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: It also returns true (in MongoDB.Driver 2.14.1) if the collection is not yet created.

Comment: mongoCollection will not return null here. so if (mongoCollection != null) will be false always