# Check document Existence before find in mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb-query

I have a Collection (or Table) with no document (or Record), and when i try to find document, i get an exception.
Is there any way to be able to check if a collection has document then trying for find document with mongo c# driver 2.0.1.

```
  var sc = new SaadatContext();
            var lastSlides =
                await 
                sc.SliderCollection.Find(slider => slider.IsDeleted == false && slider.Publish == false)
                    .SortByDescending(slider => slider.CreationDate)
                    .Limit(count).ToListAsync();
```

if collection has no document, query throw exception!, i want check collection document existence before try to find or return null if collection has no document.

pseudocode like this :

```
if( dataBase.Collection<Person>().hasRow) { call Find() method }
```

Comment: Show the code you're using to find the whole document!

Comment: Put it in your question...

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25017219/how-to-check-if-collection-exists-in-mongodb-using-c-sharp-driver

Comment: @FireAlkazar : this  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25017219/how-to-check-if-collection-exists-in-mongodb-using-c-sharp-driver) checks collection existence but i want to check whether specific collection have any record or not.