# How to know if a collection exists Mongodb C# Version 2 or older

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to update some code to the new version of Mongodb driver for c#, version 2 or newer, but it seems that the `CollectionExists()` method was deprecated, it used to work in the old version but not anymore. How can I know if a collection exists already with the new driver?

```
public static IMongoCollection<T> GetCollectionSafe<T>(string collectionName)
{                
    var db = GetDatabase();
    if (!db.CollectionExists(collectionName)) //throws error
    {
         db.CreateCollection(collectionName);
    }
    return db.GetCollection<T>(collectionName);
}
```

`GetDatabase()` is of type `IMongoDatabase` . I just want to know if a collection with a certain name exists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if collection exists in MongoDB using C# driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25017219/how-to-check-if-collection-exists-in-mongodb-using-c-sharp-driver)

Answer (score 3):

You can check existence of the collection by following code

```
public async Task<bool> CheckCollection(IMongoDatabase database, string collectionName)
{
    var filter = new BsonDocument("name", collectionName);
    var collectionCursor = await database.ListCollectionsAsync(new ListCollectionsOptions {Filter = filter});
    return await collectionCursor.AnyAsync();
}
```

P.S. Method `GetCollection` is safe for using. You don't need to check existence of the collection. It was done by driver itself.

Answer (score 0):

This code fails on my database:

```
database.ListCollections(new ListCollectionsOptions { 
    Filter = new BsonDocument { { "name", collectionName } } })
```

I get the following error message:

> The GuidRepresentation for the reader is CSharpLegacy, which requires
>   the binary sub type to be UuidLegacy, not UuidStandard

The collection in question was created the MongoDb sink for Serilog with GuidRepresentation = CSharpLegacy.

This code works without problems (with mongo driver v. 2.5.0):

```
database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collectionName) != null
```

Comment: The check `database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collectionName) != null ` does not seem to work (Mongodb 3.6.4, driver v.2.5.0). I tried it with this code which will try for a new collection each time `db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()) != null` and it seems to always be true.

Answer (score 0):

In new version of MongoDB.Driver 2.9.3 for checking the collection existence and then create it , you can use this code:

```
var dbset = typeof(T).Name;
var tables = MongoDb.ListCollectionNames().ToList();
if (!tables.Any(x => x == dbset))
{
    MongoDb.CreateCollection(dbset);
}
return MongoDb.GetCollection<T>(dbset);
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried by using ?

```
db.GetCollection("collectionName").Exists()
```

[How to check if collection exists in MongoDB using C# driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25017219/how-to-check-if-collection-exists-in-mongodb-using-c-sharp-driver)

Comment: It doesn't exist in `MongoDB.Driver.dll`